# Oracle - Insert special characters using VB.NET

Tags: oracle, vb.net

How to insert special characters using VB.NET?

Exmaple query is

```
INSERT INTO MESSAGES 
(
    MANAGEMENT_NO,
    MSG,
    MSG_TOTAL)
VALUES 
(
    'MSG220212011054160001',
    'Thank you ',
    'see you later '
)
```

When I insert that query direct to Oracle using Toad, It insert .

But I try to insert using VB.NET,  is disappered.

I used N keyword, but it same result.

```
N'Thank you ', -> 'Thank you'
N'see you later ' -> 'see you later'
```

Database chracterset is this.

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

Oracle 19c and .Netframework is 4.0

EDIT:
Here My simple code for test.

```
Dim sSql As String = ""
Dim OleCmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()
Dim conn As OracleConnection  = New OracleConnection(connectionString)

sSql   = "     INSERT INTO MESSAGES "
sSql & = "     ("
sSql & = "         MANAGEMENT_NO,"
sSql & = "         MSG,"
sSql & = "         MSG_TOTAL)"
sSql & = "     VALUES "
sSql & = "     ("
sSql & = "         'MSG220212011054160001',"
sSql & = "         'Thank you ',"
sSql & = "         'see you later '"
sSql & = "     )"

OleCmd.CommandText = sSql
OleCmd.Connection = Conn
OleCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim result As Integer = OleCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()
```

How can I do?

Comment: If you are prompted for more information and you provide it, it's a good idea to add a comment saying so. We will get a notification for a comment where we won't for a change to the question.

Comment: OT, VB has supported multiline `String` literals for quite some time and supported XML literals before that, so there's no need to use all that concatenation to build long `Strings`. Those alternatives tend to be less error-prone.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Oracle as SQL Server but you first implied that you were forcing the text data type to `nvarchar` or the like but I see no `N` prefix in your actual code. Can you add that prefix and does it make a difference? Also, is there any difference if you use parameters?